# some confusion about singleton set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the set  $\{0\}$ is closed in $(\mathbb{R} , |.|)$ ? where  $|.|$ denotes  the usual  metric on $\mathbb{R}$

My attempt :  yes , because  i think $\{0\}$  is not  open  for all  $x> 0, (x- \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \notin \{0\}$

Is its  correct?

Any hints/solution

Comment: In a metric space, [a finite set is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317678/a-finite-set-is-closed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Asserting that $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ means that $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb R$. That is what you should try to prove (and it is not hard). But the assertion “$\{0\}$ is not open for all $x>0$, $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\notin\{0\}$” makes no sense.

Comment: I think...the OP tried to show that $\{0\}$ is not open, but this should have been balls with centre $0$ instead of $x>0$...(and of course not open does not imply closed)

Comment: @CalvinKhor You are probably right.

Answer (score 3):

"Not open" does not imply closed. What you need to show is that the complement $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is open, e.g. by writing $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ as a union of open intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Take any sequence in $\{0\}$. Then it must be the zero sequence and thus converges to 0, which lies in the set. So $\{0\}$ is closed.