# Let (X, d) be a metric space in which a finite subset A of X is dense. Determine all open sets in (X, d).

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This is the question given to us. I know the conditions for an open set but I don't know how to find it when we have been given that A of X is dense. Can someone help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Every finite subset $F$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is a closed subset of $X$, and therefore $\overline F=F$.

Comment: Can you explain in detail

Comment: Since $F$ is dense, $\overline F=X$. But $\overline F=F$. Therefore, $X=F$. That is, $X$ is finite. And on a finite metric space every set is open.

Comment: So every set is open is an example of this

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Okk..Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by F= F

Comment: Where did I write that $F=F$?

Comment: I meant F bar = F

Comment: It means that $F$ is equal to its own closure. That's true for all closed sets (and only for those sets).

Comment: Ok.Thank you very much

Comment: Can you tell me why every finite subset F of a metric space is a closed subset of X

Comment: You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317678/a-finite-set-is-closed).